# Why isn't Laravel Valet working with homebrew on Catalina?

Tags: laravel-valet

On a new MacBook Pro (Catalina), I have done the following:

- Install homebrew
- `brew install php`
- Install composer
- `composer require laravel/valet`
- `valet install`
- `valet tld localhost`

When I ping foo.localhost, I get: 
`cannot resolve test.localhost: Unknown host`

Also, if I try to view a site in the browser eg `test.localhost` (which has a very basic index.html), then I get a not found error.

I have read all the previous answers and deleting everything and reinstalling didn't work.

Has anyone else come across this/have a solution?

Comment: I got a bit further with this and it looks like it was something to do with the php@7.1 formula from homebrew not having  a php-fpm module, which made nginx break. I will ask a separate question as it seems to be a separate issue.